# Get all existing JTextField components in a window and add popup menu to each?

Tags: java, swing

I need to get all existing TextFields in an app window so that I can be able to automatically add popup menus to all of them. How do you do that?

The code is below. How come when I call:
**JTextFieldRegularPopupMenu.addToAll(jpanel)** it works fine and affects all relevant JTextFields. But when I do it with a JDialog from a regular JDialog netbeans class - **JTextFieldRegularPopupMenu.addToAll(this)**, it doesn't work. What could be the problem?

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.undo.*;

public class JTextFieldRegularPopupMenu {
    public static void addToAll(Container frm) {
        JTextField txtTmp = null;
        Component[] components = frm.getComponents();

        for(int i=0;i<components.length;i++){
            if( components[i] instanceof JTextField ){
                txtTmp = (JTextField)components[i];
                addTo(txtTmp);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void addTo(JTextField txtField) 
    {
        JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
        UndoManager undoManager = new UndoManager();
        txtField.getDocument().addUndoableEditListener(undoManager);


        Action undoAction = new AbstractAction("Undo") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                if (undoManager.canUndo()) {
                    undoManager.undo();
                }
                else {
                  // No Undo
                }
            }
        };

       Action copyAction = new AbstractAction("Copy") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                txtField.copy();
            }
        };

        Action cutAction = new AbstractAction("Cut") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                txtField.cut();
            }
        };

        Action pasteAction = new AbstractAction("Paste") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                txtField.paste();
            }
        };

        Action selectAllAction = new AbstractAction("Select All") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                txtField.selectAll();
            }
        };

        cutAction.putValue(Action.ACCELERATOR_KEY, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control X"));
        copyAction.putValue(Action.ACCELERATOR_KEY, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control C"));
        pasteAction.putValue(Action.ACCELERATOR_KEY, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control V"));
        selectAllAction.putValue(Action.ACCELERATOR_KEY, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control A"));

        popup.add (undoAction);
        popup.addSeparator();
        popup.add (cutAction);
        popup.add (copyAction);
        popup.add (pasteAction);
        popup.addSeparator();
        popup.add (selectAllAction);

       txtField.setComponentPopupMenu(popup);
    }
}
```

Netbeans JFrame Class

```
public class FrmAddNewUser extends javax.swing.JDialog {

    /**
     * Creates new form FrmAddNewUser
     */

    public FrmAddNewUser(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
        super(parent, modal);
        initComponents();
        myInitComponents();
    }   

    private void myInitComponents()
    {
        JTextFieldRegularPopupMenu.AddToAll(this); //this doesn't work... but works on jpanel objects..
    }
```

Comment: A JFrame does not usually contain JTextField objects.  It contains JPanel object which may contain other JPanel objects ... and eventually some of those may contain JTextField objects.  You’ll need a recursive search.

Comment: Method names should NOT start with an upper case character. Learn and use the Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying make a uniform change to all existing JTextFields, correct? This really depends, but storing all of the objects in a data structure like an ArrayList might be your best bet. Then use a for loop to apply the same change at each index.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can't really do that in advance because windows and components are not all created at the start of an application. So you would need to manage this dynamically as an application creates and displays a window.

One way might be to use a `KeyboardFocusManager` to listen for focus changes.

When focus changes you can then invoke the `getPopupMenuComponent()` method to get the popup menu of the component. If the menu is null, then you need to add your popup menu.

Check out [Global Event Listeners](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/08/30/global-event-listeners/) for a simple example using this concepts that shows how to select all the text when a text field gains focus.

So you would need to modify all your applications to add this listener when you start the application.

Edit:

Using your current approach you would want to pass in a `Window` object to a method. Then you can use the `getContentPane()` method to get the contain holding the components.

Then you can use a class like [Swing Utils](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/13/swing-utils/). This will do a recursive search of the content pane to find all components. Then you iterate through the List and add your logic.

Then this code will work for both frames, dialogs etc.

Also, you don't need to always create custom Actions. You can use Actions from the DefaultEditorKit. For example:

```
JMenuItem copy = new JMenuItem( new DefaultEditorKit.CopyAction() );
```

The Action can be shared by all menu items.

Or you can look up the default Action from the ActionMap of the text field. See [Key Bindings](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/) for the action name to use for the lookup. It will also show you the default key binding used for the Action.

Comment: Your example looks nothing like my suggestion. It also assumes 1) that only a single panel is added to the frame. If you use nested panels it won't fine your text fields 2) You also don't handle the creation of additional dialogs etc. I gave you a simple approach to handle all of the above.